# glassfish 4.1 and cluster with JMS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, cluster-computing

I have create the cluster "mycluster", two local instance and the resources jms/Queue1, jms/Queue2  and jms/Topic with target server and cluster.

So in this way I created the cluster:

```
- create-cluster mycluster

- create-instance --node localhost-domain1 --cluster mycluster instance01

- create-instance --node localhost-domain1 --cluster mycluster instance02

[...]

- start-cluster mycluster

- deploy --target mycluster Coo.ear

Application deployed with name Coo.
```

```
Warning: Command _deploy did not complete successfully on server instance instance01: remote failure: Failed to load the application on instance instance01. The application will not run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy.

Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error. Please see server.log for more details.

Warning: Command _deploy did not complete successfully on server instance instance02: remote failure: Failed to load the application on instance instance02. The application will not run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy.
 
Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy completed with warnings.

[...]

On [server]: hostname:8080/FE-war/ all right.

On [instance01 the cluster] hostname:28080/FE-war

and

On [instance02 the cluster] hostname:28081/FE-war
```

I get this desperate HTTP status 404 - Not Found ((((

Complete logs file server, instance01, instance02, [...]:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7CqU8774DG8RGx0VkRVeEZXclE&usp=sharing

```
2016-02-06T17:00:24.593+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/home/glassfish/glassfish4/glassfish/nodes/localhost-domain1/Coo1/applications/ejb-timer-service-app/WEB-INF/classes/___EJB__Timer__App.ejb] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1454774410800] [timeMillis: 1454774424593] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Errore di connessione al server localhost sulla porta 1527 con messaggio Connessione rifiutata.
Error Code: 0
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database/datasource is not configured correctly. It currently wants to connect to the database on `localhost:1527`, but that means that each instance will try to connect to a database local to itself. Obviously this is not what you want - you want your app to always connect to the same database no matter what instance is being used.

You need to edit the datasource in your cluster config to use a proper hostname so that each instance connects to, for example, `dbserver:1527` and, if this is a production deployment, change your database from Derby to something else (e.g. MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL etc). Apache Derby is not appropriate for production use.

Comment: How can I configure a database for EJB Timer running under Glassfish cluster ? I have create:

asadmin create-cluster carcluster,

asadmin create-instance --node localhost-domain1 --cluster carcluster Coo1 / Coo2 / Coo3,

asadmin create-resource-ref --target carcluster jdbc/__default,

asadmin set resources.jdbc-connection-pool.DerbyPool.property.serverName=localhost,

asadmin set configs.config.cluster_name-config.ejb-container.ejb-timer-service.timer-datasource=jdbc/__default. And  create  3 JMQ Queue and 1 Topic for cluster and server

Answer (score 1):

To start the derby database server on one of the cluster hosts or the DAS host run.

```
asadmin start-database
```

You will also need to reconfigure the URL for the jdbc/__default datasource in the administration console. Select the Additional Properties tab of the DerbyPool connection pool and change serverName from localhost to the hostname of the server you started the database on.

[image: JDBC Settings for the DerbyPool]

Comment: My Derby Pool is http://imgur.com/cXucGiN and jdb/__default is http://imgur.com/DSnsAIi

asadmin start-database
Starting database in Network Server mode on host 0.0.0.0 and port 1527.
Versione: CSS10100/10.10.2.0 - (1582446)  Build: 1582446  ID prodotto DRDA: CSS10100
[...]
Server di rete Apache Derby: 10.10.2.0

Comment: asadmin deploy --target carcluster Coo1.ear ,
"https://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/COO1" created successfully. Failure: Command disable failed on server instance Coo1: remote failure: Application not registered Failure: Command disable failed on server instance Coo2: remote failure: Application not registered Failure: Command disable failed on server instance Coo3: remote failure: Application not registered Warning: Command _deploy did not complete successfully on server instance

Comment: Coo1: remote failure: Failed to load the application on instance Coo1. The application will not run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy. Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error. Please see server.log for more details. Warning: Command _deploy did not complete successfully on server instance Coo2: remote failure: Failed to load the application on instance Coo2. The application will not run properly. Please fix your application and redeploy. Exception while loading the app : EJB Co .... msg.seeServerLog

Comment: I added new log:  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7CqU8774DG8RGx0VkRVeEZXclE&usp=sharing

Comment: There is nothing in the logs but, looks like the servers still can't get a connection to the database on the host. There is no errors or evidence of any attempt to deploy anything in the other logs;
  Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException:   Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Errore di connessione al server baviera1.homeunix.org sulla porta 1527 con messaggio Connessione rifiutata.

Comment: Now I wrote:
asadmin start-database --dbhost baviera1.homeunix.org,

netstat -a | grep 1527
tcp6       0      0 baviera1.homeunix.:1527 [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 baviera1.homeunix:42058 baviera1.homeunix.:1527 TIME_WAIT

Comment: Redeploy on cluster I aways get "localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/…; created successfully. Failure: Command disable failed on server instance Coo1: remote failure:[...] I get back log https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7CqU8774DG8RGx0VkRVeEZXclE&usp=sharing

Comment: [SEVERE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/home/glassfish/glassfish4/glassfish/nodes/localhost-domain1/Coo1/applications/ejb-timer-service-app/WEB-INF/classes/___EJB__Timer__App.ejb] 
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException: Errore di connessione al server [..]

Comment: I get: "HTTP status 404 - Not Found", each cluster instance :-((